# Error code while downloading cloud free mosaic Sentinel-2 image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, sentinel-2

I'm trying to create a composite image of 2 Sentinel-2 images to make it cloud free using the semi-automatic classification plugin on QGIS, but when I press 'run' in 'mosaic band sets' in the plugin I receive the following error message (also I am new to QGIS and have never used Python before).

How can I resolve this issue?

```
2020-12-21T19:48:47     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/heidi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\mosaicbandsets.py", line 69, in mosaicAction
  self.mosaicBandSets()
  File "C:/Users/heidi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\maininterface\mosaicbandsets.py", line 228, in mosaicBandSets
  File "C:/Users/heidi/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 6912, in addRasterLayer
  for i in range(len(mcList)):
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setName'
```

Comment: Make sure you've updated to the latest version. If error persists, [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/382655/edit) to include debug info (see "[How can I report an error?](https://semiautomaticclassificationmanual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-can-i-report-an-error)"). You can also [report the issue](https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues/new/choose) to the plugin developer .

Comment: You can also use the [`sentinel-mosaic`](https://pypi.org/project/sentinel-mosaic/) module. See [this post](https://wsdookadr.github.io/posts/p5/) for more details on usage.